# Docker Hub Remtoe Build Triggers

Tags: docker, dockerhub

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#remote-build-triggers

Docker hub now has a build system in place. One of the ways to trigger a container to be built is using Remote build triggers. COmmands such as the following:

```
$ curl --data build=true -X POST https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/svendowideit/testhook/trigger/be579c82-7c0e-11e4-81c4-0242ac110020/
```

Their website shows a few paramters that can be passed in. But does not explain their meaning, nor do they provide a list all possible parameters.

What are all the possible parameters and what are their meanings?

Answer (score 5):

it works for branches for sure, not sure about tags:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"source_type": "Branch", "source_name": "develop"}' \
  -X POST "$DOCKERHUB_TRIGGER";
```

Try `source_type` = `Tag`

Comment: This also works for the new version of build triggers. Further, when using regex for the Docker Tag, this (source_type Branch/Tag) seems to be the only option...